# Not closing the window with click

Tags: javascript

I want to close the overlay when I click outside the overlay window.   I expect the following line to accomplish that task.  But, it doesn't.

```js
var sidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "30%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == sidenav) {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == sidenav) {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
}
```

```css
 *{
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#container{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.sidenav {
    height: 72%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #6a6c6d;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top:50px;
  }
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black ;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 50px;  
  }
.sidenav .ptext {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
    font-size: 16px; 
    color: black; 
  }
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 0px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 60px;}   
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"> &times;</a>
  <a href="#">  Mission</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a> 
</div>

<div id="header">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;Menu</span>
 
</div>

<div  id="container">
  <img class="owl1" src="bookkeepings.png" alt="" width="60" height="auto" alt="A "/>
     <p></p>Learning JavaScript</p>
</div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

The window doesn't close with a click outside the window.   But, in the following.  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal  it works.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: What made you think that `.style.width = "0";` would work? Why not `.remove()` or `.style.display = 'none';`?

Comment: The overlay closes with pressing X.  Overlay opening and closing is controlled by width o% and 30%.   I tried with display none for pressing outside the window overay.  It didn't work.   Thanks for you input

Comment: Set focus to the overlay when it's displayed. If mouse is clicked test for which element was clicked.  if the element clicked was not the overly close the overlay.

Comment: I think you `if (event.target == sidenav)` is the main issue. Need to figure out "is the element clicked outside of/not part of the sidenav" - testing if the element clicked on is sidenav OR a child - or not of sidenav I'd think would be the answer. So if not sidenav or a child of sidenav -> close it